# How do I check whether an object is an instance of a constructor in Nan 2?

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon, node.js-nan

Nan 1.x had a function `NanHasInstance(Persistent<FunctionTemplate>&, Handle<Value>)` to check whether an object is an instance of a constructor. However, that function was removed in nan 2.0, and there isn't an obvious replacement. Does nan still expose this functionality in some other way? If not, is there some other way to check it that is compatible across Node versions?

Comment: @AlanStokes Thank you. I was looking for that tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can port it with that [cool bash script](https://gist.github.com/thlorenz/7e9d8ad15566c99fd116) by Thorsten Lorenz.

But basically the signature is

```
Nan::New(\\1)->HasInstance(\\2)
```

Or in v8 I think it's [here](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/io.js-1.8/d4/da0/v8_8h_source.html)